# vim make arrow keys work like most normal programs

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I recently found VIM and started using it. I found the arrows and backspace to be flawed.
so I did this to the backspace

```
set backspace+=indent,eol,start
```

how can this be done to the arrow key to allow normal navigation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say exactly what aspect of the arrow keys you think is "flawed", so I'll just have to guess.

You can use the `whichwrap` setting to get part of what you probably want. From `:help whichwrap`:

```
'whichwrap' 'ww'    string  (Vim default: "b,s", Vi default: "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Allow specified keys that move the cursor left/right to move to the
    previous/next line when the cursor is on the first/last character in
    the line.  Concatenate characters to allow this for these keys:
        char   key    mode  ~
         b    <BS>   Normal and Visual
         s    <Space>    Normal and Visual
         h    "h"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         l    "l"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         <    <Left>     Normal and Visual
         >    <Right>    Normal and Visual
         ~    "~"    Normal
         [    <Left>     Insert and Replace
         ]    <Right>    Insert and Replace
    For example: >
        :set ww=<,>,[,]
    allows wrap only when cursor keys are used.
    When the movement keys are used in combination with a delete or change
    operator, the <EOL> also counts for a character.  This makes "3h"
    different from "3dh" when the cursor crosses the end of a line.  This
    is also true for "x" and "X", because they do the same as "dl" and
    "dh".  If you use this, you may also want to use the mapping
    ":map <BS> X" to make backspace delete the character in front of the
    cursor.
    When 'l' is included and it is used after an operator at the end of a
    line then it will not move to the next line.  This makes "dl", "cl",
    "yl" etc. work normally.
    NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
    set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

In your case, you probably want:

```
:set whichwrap+=<,>
```

This will make left and right wrap around line endings.

You can also try mapping `<Up>` and `<Down>` to `gk` and `gj` in normal and visual modes if the distinction between logical and display lines is confusing you. Alternatively, you could `:set nowrap` to remove the distinction altogether.